# How to split a pdf and preserve thumbnail labels?

Tags: c#, itext

I have a pdf that has some pages that need to be removed based on the (thumbnail) label of the page. So, I am using the the PdfCopy.GetImportedPage(...) method to copy only the wanted pages but found that the thumbnail label (page label) gets removed. The only way I am able to add pagelabels is to use a Writer, but then I can't copy pages. Can someone help me here to setup the right construction ?

```
public Boolean SplitByList(string povDocument, string povOutputDocument, PageLabelList povPageList)
{
    PdfReader lorReader = null;
    Document lorDocument = null;
    PdfCopy lorPdfCopyProvider = null;
    PdfImportedPage lorImportedPage = null;
    PdfPageLabels lorLbls = null;

    try
    {
        // Intialize a new PdfReader instance with the contents of the source Pdf file:
        lorReader = new PdfReader(povDocument);
        lorLbls = new PdfPageLabels();
        if (povPageList == null || povPageList.GetLength() == 0) return false;
        Boolean lbvFirstPage = false;
        for (int livCntr = 1; livCntr <= povPageList.GetLength(); livCntr++)
        {
            PageLabel lorLabel = povPageList.GetItemAt(livCntr);
            if (lorLabel != null && lorLabel.lbvPublish)
            {
                // Do only the first time
                if (!lbvFirstPage)
                {
                    lbvFirstPage = true;
                    lorDocument = new Document(lorReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(lorLabel.livPageNumber));

                    // Initialize an instance of the PdfCopyClass with the source document and an output file stream:
                    lorPdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(lorDocument, new System.IO.FileStream(povOutputDocument, System.IO.FileMode.Create));
                    lorDocument.Open();
                }
                // Extract the desired page number:
                lorImportedPage = lorPdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(lorReader, lorLabel.livPageNumber);
                lorLbls.AddPageLabel(livCntr, 1, lorLabel.lorPageLabel);
                lorPdfCopyProvider.AddPage(lorImportedPage);
            }
        }
        lorPdfCopyProvider.Close();
        lorDocument.Close();
        lorReader.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lorDocument.Close();
        lorReader.Close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the page label.

[image]